# vault plugin integration with backstage is not working

Tags: hashicorp-vault, backstage

Team,
I followed this [Hashicorp vault with backstage](https://roadie.io/backstage/plugins/hashicorp-vault/) and it is getting me 404 and also trying v1 where as i called out 2. any hint what I might be missing or is it a bug?

```
  annotations:
    backstage.io/linguist: 'https://github.com/backstage/backstage/tree/master/plugins/playlist'
    vault.io/secrets-path: sc/prod/mso-team/jenkins/
    vault.io/secrets-engine: secrets
```

```
vault:
  baseUrl: https://vault.team.com
  token: hvs.xxxxx
  secretEngine: 'secrets' # Optional. Default: 'secrets'
  kvVersion: '2' # Optional. The available options are '1' or '2'
```

error

```
[1] 2023-12-11T23:35:29.462Z backstage info ::1 - - [11/Dec/2023:23:35:29 +0000] "GET /api/vault/v1/secrets/sc%2Fprod%2Fmso-teams%2Fjenkins%2F?engine=secrets HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://localhost:3000/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" type=incomingRequest
```